# Handle storing card details when using multiple payment providers

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, credit-card

It's a common feature for payment providers to have a medium to store card details(which returns a reference you can always use to charge a card).

We plan on leveraging multiple payment providers, considering that our product is used by various regions (both to support the locally available cards and alongside maintain low payment charges incurred by the customer, based on their location).

Now the challenge is that each time we integrate a new payment provider, it'll require that we replicate/store all of our existing users' card details (already stored on other payment providers we leverage on) on the new provider we'll be integrating with.

Knowing fully well that:

- We don't store users' card
- Previously integrated payment providers don't return complete card details (just reference).
- Payment providers cannot allow transferring card details to another provider.

I'm hereby seeking an alternative solution (that doesn't require storing card).

I saw something close to what we could rely on(https://www.spreedly.com/). Are there also alternatives to this?

Comment: Can't you just store the card with the appropriate payment provider for their location? "Oh, this user is from the US, use Stripe."

Comment: Is storing the card once per payment provider that much of an overhead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, your only options are to use a vaulting product like Spreedly or become PCI certified yourself - and using a vaulting product is going to be a lot easier to deal with than the PCI certification you'll need to store the cards yourself.